# Replacing html tags around some text, with plotly/dash html components

Tags: html, python-3.x, string, parsing, plotly-dash

I have an html file, the content is a table such as:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <p>Item 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Definition for Item 1.</p>
            <p>This may contain several paragraphs.</p>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>
            <p>Item 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Definition for Item 2.</p>
            <p>This may contain several paragraphs.</p>
            <p>And another paragraph here.</p>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to create a dict that would look like this (using [dash html components](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components)):

```
items_dict = {
   'Item 1': html.Div([
        html.P("""definition for Item 1"""),
        html.P("""This may contain several paragraphs."""),
    ]),
    'Item 2': html.Div([
        html.P("""definition for Item 2"""),
        html.P("""This may contain several paragraphs."""),
        html.P("""And another paragraph here."""),
    ]),
}
```

How would you do this?

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thank you,
David

Some context: I have a table with close to 100 items and their definition. I am trying to create a pythonique object that i can search based on the item name (string).

My items/definitions are in a Word file, that I have changed into an HTML file using the [Mammoth](https://pypi.org/project/mammoth/) package.

However, there may be a better way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can parse the HTML with [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) into a plain dictionary.

You can then convert the dictionary to objects you need.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<tr>
        <td>
            <p>Item 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Definition for Item 1.</p>
            <p>This may contain several paragraphs.</p>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>
            <p>Item 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Definition for Item 2.</p>
            <p>This may contain several paragraphs.</p>
            <p>And another paragraph here.</p>
        </td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

out = {}
for row in soup.select("tr"):
    header, *definitions = row.select("td")
    header = header.get_text(strip=True)
    for p in definitions[0].select("p"):
        out.setdefault(header, []).append(p.get_text(strip=True))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Item 1": ["Definition for Item 1.", "This may contain several paragraphs."],
    "Item 2": [
        "Definition for Item 2.",
        "This may contain several paragraphs.",
        "And another paragraph here.",
    ],
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, that looks like a great solution, thank you! As Beautifulsoup can also parse XML. I will look into working straight with the .docx file.